# Displaying array content in alert box

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This DOES WORK in other scripts I have written, but not here. Why?
Other scripts I have written have been able to display the entire array,
and were able to display 1-2-3 levels deep.
ie Original[0] / Original[0][0]
Am I missing something VERY simple?

Winning answer HERE:
[How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript?rq=1)
Works fine?

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
Original = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
[0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
[q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p],
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j],
];

function TestFunction(){
alert(Original);
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick = TestFunction()>Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that you  have a bunch of undeclared variables. In an array, strings must be enclosed in quotation marks.

```
Original = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
[0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p'],
['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
];
```

Here is an updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4fmtqou2/

Comment: Ahh, ok, good. I was in too big of a hurry. This was actually a prep question for the next one,.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RonK/hgtxzkrs/2/  Here is more what the TOTAL problem was. But could not get even the pieces to work first.

Answer (score 2):

You should quote your "q","w","e" ... characters in the array.

Comment: Yep, otherwise they are just undefined variables. Fixing this by wrapping them in quotes fixes the problem

Comment: innerHTML throws out an "undefined" at this point. I wish alert would do the same... wait... Has anyone seen it? thinking back, I swear I'd seen it before.